# Centering text vertically with CSS

Tags: css, alignment

How can I vertically center text in an element?

For example, from this:

[image: an example]

to this:

[image: second example]

I know I can specify the `height` property on the text and then use

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
margin: 0;
```

but I don't want this because the `height` of the text is variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this out:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-to-align-text-vertically-center-in-div-with-css

HTML:

```
<div>
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: normal;      
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CtH9k/)